# FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures

Tags: jenkins, build, devops

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test:uit:testFirexCollector'.

  > Process 'command 'pytest'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test:uit:testFirexE2E'.

  > Process 'command 'pytest'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test:uit:testOrgPeopleCollector'.

  > Process 'command 'pytest'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test:uit:testPrrqCollector'.

  > Process 'command 'pytest'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Information provided in your question doesn't help. I see that something related to some test failed and it's Python related. With this much information, how do you expect anyone will be able to help you out? :) You should post some code snippet that was part of the above tasks. Also, if i see above, it says, run with `--stacktrace`  option etc. Did you try anything? If you haven't, then please do so. Put some effort. Later, if it's still not working, then post it here.

Comment: Reading the following link will help you in the long run if you wish to seek help here or any other forum: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ :)